# Words order in the question about time duration

Tags: questions

There is a mathematical model that can give a forecast for some duration (hours, days, years). But the forecast will not be equally accurate for different periods of time. How should I ask for what period of time the forecast is most accurate?

1. What is duration, the model can give most accurate forecast.
2. For what duration....
3. What is duration for....

Which of the above is correct? Where can I read about this rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of the full context, but here goes.

1. What is **the** duration **for which** the model can give **the** most accurate forecast?
2. For **which** duration **can** the model give the best forecast?
3. see #1.

In all above cases, "period" might be more apt than "duration".  For example, a forecast for tomorrow has the *same duration* as the forecast for the day after tomorrow, but they are separate, unique *periods*.